# how to put in selectInput of R.shiny many levels with few line of code

Tags: r, shiny, paste, levels, selectinput

I want to put in selectInput of Rshiny all the levels of a variable (which is character) with the few lines of code.

```
var<-c("a","a","b","b","c","d")
```

I want to have something like this

```
c("a"="a", "b"="b", "c"="c", "d"="d")
```

then like this

```
c("Whole a"="="a", "Whole b"="b", "Whole c"="c", "Whole d=","d")
```

`"Whole a"` for example means I want to write complete names of the levels (begining with a capital letter and having space between two words).

The first solution I thought of is to use `paste()`.

```
paste (unique(var),"=",unique(var),collapse = ",")
```

which give as ouput

```
"a = a, b= b, c = c, d = d"
```

However, I know these codes are insufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create a named vector? something like this.

```
setNames(unique(var), paste('Whole', unique(var)))

#Whole a Whole b Whole c Whole d 
#    "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"
```

Comment: So met me clarify, something like this `c("Cancer"="a", "Heart disease"="b"` ), without rewriting each time variable levels (that is `"a"` ,`"b"` ...)

Comment: I don't get it, where am I rewriting variables levels in my answer?

Comment: I think your scripts answer my questions @Ronak Shah